How to display input sent to console program from a bash script?
My console program runs under Ubuntu 20.04. When run interactively, the input expression (e.g., a+b below) is displayed next to the prompt followed by the output on a new line as follows. I would like to achieve this same format when providing the input to the program from a bash script.
$ ./rec_desc1
Enter expression: a+b
F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
Q --> eps
Q --> +TQ
E --> TQ
Success. 

But if I send the input from a bash script via here-string or piping it (as suggested at How do I provide input to a C program from bash?), the input is not displayed and unfortunately the first line of output is shifted up next to prompt as shown below.
cat rec_desc1_unit_test
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test case 1"
./rec_desc1 <<< a+b

$ ./rec_desc1_unit_test
Test case 1
Enter expression: F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
Q --> eps
Q --> +TQ
E --> TQ
Success. 

Is there a way to pass the input from a bash script so that it displays next to the prompt and is followed by a newline so it matches the interactive case above?
I eventually want to run numerous test cases for different expressions from a bash script and would like to have the self-documentation of the input expression being displayed. I could call set -v prior to invoking the console program in order to display the input if necessary (as shown below). Then I would need to call set +v immediately afterward to avoid displaying the echo statements that describe the next test case. I would like to avoid surrounding each test case with set -v and set +v if possible.
$ cat rec_desc1_unit_test
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test case 1"
set -v
./rec_desc1 <<< a+b

$ ./rec_desc1_unit_test
Test case 1
./rec_desc1 <<< a+b
Enter expression: F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
F --> id
R --> eps
T --> FR
Q --> eps
Q --> +TQ
E --> TQ
Success. 


It'd be easier to do this from within ./rec_desc1

Better would be perhaps to change the C program so it doesn't display the prompt when input isn't a terminal, and/or implement an option to provide input on the command line.

The fact that rec_desc1 is a C program, and what it does with it's input is irrelevant to your question assuming you don't want that to change.
Here's a shell script that produces the behavior you describe, i.e. prompts for input and produces some output based on that input (in this case print a series of numbers):
$ cat rec_desc1
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf 'Enter a number: ' >&2
if IFS= read -r rsp; then
    seq "$rsp"
    printf 'Success.\n' >&2
fi

Here it is being run manually:
$ ./rec_desc1
Enter a number: 3
1
2
3
Success.

Here is the equivalent of your test script calling it:
$ cat rec_desc1_unit_test
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf 'Test case 1\n'
./rec_desc1 <<< 3

and the output that produces:
$ ./rec_desc1_unit_test
Test case 1
Enter a number: 1
2
3
Success.

Now, here is a modified version of your caller test script that uses coprocesses to run the test script in the background while the calling script reads the test scripts output and writes input to it, just like someone using a terminal would do:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read2re() {
    local re="$1" str char ret=1

    while IFS= read -t 1 -n 1 -r char; do
        str="${str}${char}"
        if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then
            ret=0
            break
        fi
    done <&"${COPROC[0]}"

    printf '%s' "$str"
    return "$ret"
}

read2eof() {
    local re="$1" lastReadLine line ret=1

    while IFS= read -r line; do
        ret=0
        lastReadLine="$line"
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    done <&"${COPROC[0]}"

    if [[ -n "$re" ]] && ! [[ $lastReadLine =~ $re ]]; then
        ret=1
    fi
    return "$ret"
}

writeStr() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
}

run_test() {
    local title="$1" cmd="$2" input="$3" ret=0
    printf '%s: %s %s\n' "$title" "$cmd" "$input"

    coproc { "$cmd" 2>&1; }
    (( $ret == 0 )) && { read2re  ': ';      ret=$?; }
    (( $ret == 0 )) && { writeStr "$input";  ret=$?; }
    (( $ret == 0 )) && { read2eof 'Success'; ret=$?; }
    wait "$COPROC_PID"

    printf '========\n'
    return "$ret"
}

run_test 'Test Case 1' ./rec_desc1 3

run_test 'Test Case 2' ./rec_desc1 5

and the output that produces:
$ ./rec_desc1_unit_test
Test Case 1: ./rec_desc1 3
Enter a number: 3
1
2
3
Success.
========
Test Case 2: ./rec_desc1 5
Enter a number: 5
1
2
3
4
5
Success.
========

We can't read the initial Enter a number:  prompt from the test script, rec_desc1, with a single call to read because that prompt output doesn't end in a newline and so we need to read it 1 char at a time, with a 1 second timeout per read attempt just in case the test script stops producing output unexpectedly.
The above calls a function read2re() which stops reading a line when :  has been read. I chose that approach as it is flexible and only loosely couples the calling script to the script under test as it will work for any prompt that ends in : . If the prompt might contain multiple :  strings or may not contain that string or you have any other reason you can't use a regexp to know when when you've read it, the alternatives are:

Read a specific number of characters (but that tightly couples your calling script to the script it is testing as it then needs to know exactly how many chars are in the prompt) or
Read until the whole string matches an expected prompt (but that tightly couples your calling script to the script it is testing as it then needs to know exactly the prompt string) or
Read for a specific length of time (but that can slow your calling script down as the prompt will almost certainly be read well before the timeout expires and it could read too much if multiple writes from the test script occur at the start).

See also how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-various-shells for more information about using coprocesses.
Alternatively you could probably use expect (which I've never actually used, don't have and can't install) to do the same as I'm doing above with coprocesses.
